# Log rotation implemented but logs are not writing in log files

Tags: mongodb

I have installed the mongodb in my server and i have added the log rotation policy in the `mongod.conf` where

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  logRotate: reopen
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
```

I have also installed the logrotate in my server and added the policy in this

```
sudo nano /etc/logrotate.d/mongodb

/var/mongodb/log/*.log
{
   rotate 10
   daily
   dateext
   dateformat %Y-%m-%d-%s
   dateyesterday
   size 10000M
   missingok
   create 600 mongodb mongodb
   delaycompress
   compress
   sharedscripts
   postrotate
     /bin/kill -SIGUSR1 $(cat /var/run/mongodb.pid)
   endscript
}
```

I have given the permissions to mongodb as well ,
file is being created but the logs are not there in those files

I tried giving the permission to logs of mongodb but still no success

Answer (score 0):

You defined logfile `path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`, however your logrotate uses `/var/mongodb/log/*.log`. You mistake the folder names.

Another issue: by default `logrotate` uses statefile `/var/lib/logrotate.status` which may require according privileges. Use `logrotate --state <statefile>` for a different statefile.

Note, for the postscript I would suggest to use

```
if /usr/sbin/pidof -s mongod > /dev/null ; then kill -USR1 $( /usr/sbin/pidof mongod ) ; fi
```

It does not throw an error if your `mongod` is not running.

Comment: Use logrotate --state <statefile> for a different statefile. im not able to get you ,i have changed the path of the mongodb logs and given the permission of to logrotate.status but other logrotate --state <statefile> not able to understand

Comment: If you have write permissions on `/var/lib/logrotate.status` then you are fine and you can ignore this hint. But as said, by default folder `/var/lib/` is owned by root and has `u=rwx,go=rx`, thus by default `logrotate` fails if you run it as non-root user.